# Why is print(456 ** 5582) so fast in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried many numbers but it runs in like O(1) time. Why is this so fast? Can someone please explain how ** operator actually works.

Comment: probably square-and-multiply? how fast is it? what were you expecting? `O(1)` with respect to what?

Comment: can you explain what square-and-multiply means ? By O(1), I meant constant time.

Comment: Many numbers? Try print(456546 ** 95675582) :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it runs in like O(1) time?" We understand that this means constant time, but **constant with respect to what**? In my quick test it clearly does not scale at constant time.

Comment: Keep adding digits, it's definitely not O(1)

Comment: print is slow ... the calculation might be fast.

Comment: I believe the previous commenters meant that python may be using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring which is `O(log n)` where n is the n from `x ** n`

Comment: here is the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4183

Comment: `a=456**2872334` takes multiple seconds on my laptop

Comment: This reminds me of one professor saying in his lecture  "Let N be an arbitrary large number.... No, way, N is too big, let it be M instead". What was it about though.. Ah, right. O(1) algorithm can run million of years. The big-O notation is a measure of how the algorithm running is scaling with the different size inputs and not about the absolute running time.

Comment: I'm sorry , I guess I should have done a bit more research before posting here. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I think, the question in the title is well formulated and valuable. The answer (still incomplete) is really in the comments, I have learnt a lot from them.

Comment: I really have to disagree there. The question is vague ("so fast", and no numbers or reasoning), and based on a false premise ("runs in O(1) time"). The question "X seems fast, I think it's O(1), how is that?" with the answer "It's not" is not really useful to future visitors. But hey, up to you whether you delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim that this is O(1) is incorrect.

```
>>> %timeit 456**558 
6.22 µs ± 9.22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit 456**5582  
237 µs ± 226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit 456**55822
9.54 ms ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

See [`here`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/longobject.c#L4022) for the CPython implementation.